# Fetch Keycloak Login event data using REST API in Grafana Dashboard

Tags: api, rest, grafana

I have a REST API url, to which I need to pass authentication credentials and get the access token.

Using this access token then I need to run a different url and get the data.

How do I do this in Grafana using Infinity or any other REST API datasource plugin.

I am able to configure the infinity datasource and get the access token.
but how can I use that when I have to run the second url.

How do I do that, is there any configuration we need to achieve this functionality.

Regards,
Bhushan

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the jwt in the authorization header: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization

The usual format for JWT is `Authorization: Bearer <token>`